# Counting id for both days SQL

Tags: sql, function, analytical

Can anyone help me, please?

The task is to find the number of rides taken by drivers who took a ride on both days

```
create table rides 
(
    ride_id int, 
    driver_id int,
    ride_in_kms int, 
    ride_fare float, 
    ride_date date
);

insert into rides values (1, 1, 3, 4.45, "2016-05-16");
insert into rides values (2, 1, 4, 8.46, "2016-05-16");
insert into rides values (3, 2, 6, 11.9, "2016-05-16");
insert into rides values (4, 3, 3, 6.76, "2016-05-16");
insert into rides values (5, 2, 6, 13.55, "2016-05-16");
insert into rides values (6, 4, 3, 4.91, "2016-05-20");
insert into rides values (7, 1, 7, 16.77, "2016-05-20");
insert into rides values (8, 3, 9, 16.18, "2016-05-20");
insert into rides values (9, 2, 3, 6.07, "2016-05-20");
insert into rides values (10, 4, 4, 6.25, "2016-05-20");
```

The output:

```
driver_id  rides
--------------
1  3
2  3
3  2
```

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: `having min(date) < max(date)` or `having count(distinct date) > 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like below

```
select driver_id,count(*) as cnt
from
rides
group by driver_id
having count(distinct ride_date) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select driver_id ,count( ride_id) as rides
from rides group by driver_id having  driver_id in 
(select driver_id from rides
where ride_date ="2016-05-16" and driver_id in
(select driver_id from rides
 where ride_date="2016-05-20")) ;
```